# How to get some common data in a custom ConstraintValidator

Tags: hibernate-validator

I am validating a input class using Java validation api and hibernate validator.
i have created few custom annontation for some business validation and i am using these annotation on the input class. below is an example of such annotation validator -

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

```
public class DBColumnConstraintValidator implements   ConstraintValidator<DatabaseColumnConstraint, Object> {

private DBColumnConstraintValidator databaseColumnConstraint;

private final List<DatabaseConstraintValidationStep> steps = new ArrayList<DatabaseConstraintValidationStep>();

@Override
public void initialize(DBColumnConstraintValidator  databaseColumnConstraint) {



}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    //Validation logic 


}
```

}

I want to use some data for my validation logic inside isValid() method and this data is common and will be used by few other validator classes as well.

is there any way to set or make  that common data available to isValid() method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDI or Spring, you can simply use dependency injection (e.g. using `@Inject`) within your constraint validator implementation to obtain whatever contextual service or data your need.